# Set default packages variable for spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I trying to start spark-shell having packages variable set by an environment variable by default.

The normal execution command is
`spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0`

I would like to avoid to write always `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0` set a variable

Which is the variable that can I set in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add line

```
spark.jars.packages  com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0
```

into your spark configuration file:

> $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf

Note: this will affect any spark application, not only spark-shell.

Look more in the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties).